# Keep scientific notation when parsing String into Double

Tags: java

I'm converting user input from string to scientific notation using `Double.parseDouble()`. But I notice that this only works for the following range:

```
value with exponent number >=7 (ie: 1e7) for positive exponent or
value with exponent number <= -4 (ie: 1e-4) for negative exponent.
```

The code below converts 
        1e7 correctly as 1e7 but
        1e4 incorrectly as 10000

```
public Double convert(String value){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##E0");
    String formattedVal = df.format(value);      
    return Double.parseDouble(formattedVal);
}
```

Comment: A double has no notion of formatting. If you want a particular representation, you should apply the relevant format when converting back to string.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want as output.  You say it only "works" for a certain range, but what range do you want and what output do you want for each range?

Comment: @Oliver that's the reason why I'm using the DecimalFormat class

Comment: Wait.  Are you passing a *string* value of `"1e4"` to `df.format`?

Comment: @markspace, the input is a string which represents a number and the output should be a Double. What I want is if i input a scientific notation as string, the output to be in scientifc notation as well, not in decimal.but if the exponent is between -4 and 7 exclusive.

Comment: Can't be done.  Java (and most floating point implementations) have no notion of a "format" attached.  Once the number is parsed into a double, it no longer has a format.

Comment: @Mokoto, yes. DecimalFomat.format takes an object as argument

Comment: @markspace. I disagree. how come Double.parseDouble("1e7") is 1e7 and Double.parseDouble("1e6") is 1000000?

Comment: Well let's see you get it working then.

Comment: @Taf you are using the DecimalFormat class when parsing the String not when you convert the Double back into a String for display.

Comment: @markspace I must admit you were right. thanks for he answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double has no intrinsic format, it is just bits. What you are seeing is the result of calling toString() on your Double. By default Double.toString() will only use scientific notation under certain circumstances. If you want to have a specific notation when you convert it to a String for display use your DecimalFormat again.

```
public Double convert(String value){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##E0");
    String formattedVal = df.format(value);      
    return Double.parseDouble(formattedVal);
}

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##E0");
Double d = convert("1e4");
String dAsString = df.format(d);
System.out.println(dAsString);
```

Comment: thanks for clarify the issue. Now I understand the root of the problem.